# cout/stdout not working after execvp()

Tags: c++

So I am attempting to use `execvp()` from `unistd.h` in a short program I'm writing. However for some strange reason I seem to be losing the ability to use `cout` or even `printf` after calling the `execvp` function.

For example this works:

```
pid_t pid;
int status;
if ((pid = fork()) > 0) {
  waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
}
else {
  execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
}
cout << "DONE!" << endl;
```

But this does not work:

```
execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
cout << "DONE!" << endl;
```

And, while it is not a huge problem, I would like to understand why it is happening. I have not been able to find anything relevant when I searched here and with Google.

Not sure if this has anything at all to do with the issue but I am using the `-std=c++11` flag with `g++`.

Comment: Do you understand at all what `execvp` does? Also, it's not very helpful to tell us what works and what doesn't work without telling us what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: To a certain extent yes. However it was only very lightly covered in my CISC361 class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will not work

```
execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
cout << "DONE!" << endl;
```

Because the function `execvp()` never returns (if it succeeded).

It replaces the current processes with a new image and executes that.

On the other this works:

```
if ((pid = fork()) > 0) {
  waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
}
else {
  execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
}
cout << "DONE!" << endl;
```

What happens here is that `fork()` creates a new processes. So you now have two processes at exactly the same place.

- One processes has the variable `pid` set to zero (this is the parent). It goes into the first branch of the `if statement` and there waits for the child to finish.
- One processes has the variable `pid` set to none zero (this is the child). It goes into the second branch. It executes `execvp()` which never returns. It does not return because the processes image is replaced by another executable.

Note what you should really do is:

```
if ((pid = fork()) > 0) {
  waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
  cout << "Child Finished!" << endl;
}
else {
  execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
  // This code should never execute if everything is OK.
  cout << "Child failed to start" << endl;
  exit(1);
}
```

Comment: So I would have to do it the first way then?

Comment: `execvp()` will return when it failed to run the new program, so "never returns" isn't true.

Comment: @IanLantzy We have no idea what you're trying to do, so I'm not sure how you imagine we could answer that.

Comment: @IanLantzy: Are you looking to replace the current processes with another. Or are you wanting to spin up a child processes to do a task, then return to the original processes when the child is finished?

Comment: I am just trying to understand why what happens happens. It's a valid question and once it lets me I'll accept this answer because it explains it very nicely.